# Can I run S3 Batch copy operation job from source account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to run Batch Copy operation job to copy large amount of data from one s3 bucket to another.

Source Account: contains s3 bucket with objects.
Destination Account: contains s3 bucket with manifest, and destination s3 bucket for objects.

I need to run the Batch operation job in source account or a third account altogether.

So far, I am able to succeed in the following:

1. Run s3 batch job within same aws account  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-managing-jobs.html
2. Run s3 batch job from destination s3 bucket https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/cross-account-bulk-transfer-of-files-using-amazon-s3-batch-operations/

However when I try to create a batch job at the source account, I get errors.

- when I enter manifest file from destination account, I get error:
  `Unable to get the manifest object’s ETag. Specify a different object to continue.`
- when I enter the destination s3 bucket from destination account, I get error:
  `Insufficient permissions to access  <s3 bucket>`

Is there a way to change configurations to enable running batch job from source account?

Comment: Is there a Bucket Policy on the destination bucket that permits access by the IAM Role associated with the Batch job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Amazon S3 Batch Operation job is associated with an IAM Role.

The **IAM Role** would need permission to access the S3 bucket in the other AWS Account (or permission to access *any* S3 bucket).

In addition, the **Destination Bucket** (in the other AWS Account) will also need a **Bucket Policy** that permits that IAM Role to access the bucket (at minimum `GetObject`).

Comment: I guess it will work if I use it through cfn template and java code. When I try to create a job through console, it needs me to define the buckets and manifest before I can configure the IAM Role.

Comment: Update: It worked when I created a batch job from inside an aws lambda. So this issue may be a console specific issue.